# how to use scalaz IList

Tags: scalaz

[scala.collection.immutable.List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) defines `indexWhere`, which *returns the index of the first element of this general sequence that satisfies the predicate p, or -1, if none exists*:

```
def indexWhere(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): Int
```

so, I can use:

```
List("hello", "world").indexWhere(_.length > 10) // -1
```

However, I would prefer to get an `Option[Int]`. I see that this is implemented in [scalaz.IList](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/fabab8f699d56279d6f2cc28d02cc2b768e314d7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/IList.scala):

```
def indexWhere(f: A => Boolean): Option[Int]
```

How do I use the `scalaz.IList.indexWhere`?
    I tried importing scalaz, but I still get -1.

```
import scalaz._
import std.list._
List("hello", "world").indexWhere(_.length > 10) // -1 instead of None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val ilist = IList.fromList(List("hello", "world"))    
ilist.indexWhere(_.length > 10)  // None
ilist.indexWhere(_.length > 2)   // Some(0)
```

Comment: thx. any idea why scalaz does not provide an implicit class for IList, so that we could avoid instantiating Ilist (as it is done elsewhere in scalaz, such as `List(List(1)).join`) ?

Comment: (they could have used a different method name is that was the only problem)

Comment: I think, that is only about avoiding confusion with the same method names.